# Is there a good reason not to store password reset tokens in a key value store like redis?

Tags: redis, jwt, one-time-password

Usually I store the hashed password reset tokens in a database like MySQL.

In my current application I use JWT to reduce the number of database queries.
I also use Redis to keep track of valid JWTs, now I'm wondering why I should not just save the password reset tokens in Redis and map the token to the user id + timestamp (to deny old tokens).

The only reason I can think of is memory usage.

Is there another reason not to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would introduce a *point of failure*, namely Redis.

If keeping track of valid JWTs is a way to check a JWT for revocation, then you probably have that point of failure already. What happens if Redis is unavailable?
You would either deny access (hence the point of failure) or accept any verified JWT as valid (not revoked).

If the later is true, storing reset tokens in Redis would just make that dependency explicit: if Redis is down, you can't change password.

Comment: If redis is unavailable you can not authenticate and yes it would also not be possible to reset passwords, but if I use mysql that point of failure would be the database so how is using the database any different ?

Comment: My understanding was that the password reset token was a JWT by itself. You can then have the mapping (to user ID) signed, timestamp too (`iat`). Am I mistaken?

Comment: In any case, your DB is a point of failure on its own. Redis would be a **new** point of failure.

Comment: ah okay now I get it, but to solve this I could use the database as a fallback? The password reset token is not a JWT, it's just a token you can (only once) use to obtain a JWT (the token is a URL param and part of a reset link mailed to the user and I don't want a JWT in a get request which might be logged)

Comment: You can use the database. Since this lookup is used for a password reset, under normal circumstances it shouldn't be a performance issue.